# Python & rsync: how to deal with identical filenames?

Tags: python, filenames, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to automatically copy files to a remote server. Since space is restricted on my internal HDD, I also use `rsync` to subsequently move these files (i.e., using `--remove-source-files`) to an external HDD upon successful upload.

The files are photographs taken using a remote camera capture application, which names the files in sequence (`DSC0001.JPG`, `DSC0002.JPG`, etc.). The sequence seems to be specific to a "session": if I quit the remote capture application and start it again, it will begin at 1 (provided the folder is empty).

I have everything scripted in Python (2.6, since running on very old MacBook), so should anything crash, it is restarted again. Now, here comes the problem: should the remote capture application crash and restart, and should `rsync` have just finished uploading & moving all the files, then the JPG numbering will start again at 1. Subsequently, when `rsync` will again upload & move the new files, there will be a clash of names, since `DSC0001.JPG` already exists on the external HDD.

[From what I gather](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200061/how-does-rsync-resolve-conflicts), `rsync` will simply overwrite the duplicate, unless I specify `--ignore-existing`. But in that case the new `DSC0001.JPG` (and all subsequent images) are not synced anymore. Is there a way to solve this using `rsync` that the post I link to above missed, or is it best to deal with this in the Python script (and if so, how?)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for a method that renames the files by creation date & time (so it's always unique) before doing `rsync`. Answer found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113684:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image  # Python Image Library
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret

allImageFiles = glob.glob(pathToFolder + "*.JPG")
for imageFile in imagefiles:
    number = 0  # for duplicate check below
    time = get_exif(imageFile)["DateTimeOriginal"]
    time = time.replace(":", "")
    time = time.replace(" ", "_")
    new_name = pathToTempSyncFolder + "DSC_" + time + ".JPG"
    if new_name == imageFile:  # if file already has desired name, end current iteration of 'for'-loop (i.e., do not rename)
        print(new_name, "already ok")
        continue  
    while os.path.exists(new_name):  # safety check for duplicates
        number += 1
        new_name = pathToFolder + "DSC_" + time + "_MAYBE_DUPLICATE_"+str(number)+".JPG"
    os.rename(imageFile, new_name)  # RENAME
```